# Difference between cutting lines with 10dd and d9 in vim?

Tags: vim

If I understand correctly both commands cut 10 lines and allow you to paste them anywhere.

Are they both the same as (n-1)dd and dn+enter where n is the number of lines to be cut?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two relevant help section are copied below.

```
                                                        d
["x]d{motion}           Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register
                        x].  See below for exceptions.

                                                        dd
["x]dd                  Delete [count] lines [into register x] linewise.
```

`10dd` is the second one which deletes 10 lines from you current position.

`d9` does nothing. `d9j` (or `d9<CR>`) is delete from the cursor to where the cursor ends up (which is`9j`) is nine lines below the current one. However the `j` or `<CR>` makes it linewise so the same thing is deleted.

Both of these commands delete 10 lines. so `ndd` is equivalent to `d(n-1)j`.

`d9j` might be easier to type than `10dd` if you have `set relativenumber` turned on because the difference between the line you are on and the line you want to delete to are on the left hand side of your screen.

You can use `d9k` to delete 10 lines up from your cursor line which you can't do with `dd`. Or you can use `dfa` to delete upto and including the next a. `d{motion}` is more powerful than `dd` because it isn't restricted to only linewise deletions.

Which one you use is up to you but certain combinations are easier depending on where your cursor is.

Comment: +1 well explained. but I believe it is a typo : `ndd is equivalent to d(n+1)j`  `s/+/-/`?